# How do I drop a slash from the middle of a URL with a query string?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, querystring

I have some domain redirects that point to a page on my server, and they stick a trailing slash after the filename but before the query string.  So this:

http://hydesim.com?dll=40.71427,-74.00597&yd=10&zm=12&op=156

…becomes this:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/gmap/hydesim.html/?dll=40.71427,-74.00597&yd=10&zm=12&op=156

…instead of this:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/gmap/hydesim.html?dll=40.71427,-74.00597&yd=10&zm=12&op=156

So how do I drop that middle-of-URL slash while preserving the query string?  I’ve tried some `.htaccess` approaches but nothing seems to work.  The most recent attempt was:

`RewriteRule ^(.+)html/(.+)$  /$1html$2 [R=301,L]`

*[UPDATE: That rule didn’t work, so I disabled it, and now there are no rewrites in effect.]*  I’m not very experienced with `mod_rewrite`, as you might have guessed.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: That rewrite rule doesn't match the URL you posted. Please post the actual rewrite rules being used.

Comment: I’m not using any rewrite rules right now, as I disabled that one after it didn’t work, and there are no others (except for the domain redirect at the registrar, which appears to be where the slash comes from).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache's mod_rewrite does not match the query string in its RewriteRules. You don't even need QSA if you are not redirecting to a URL with a query string specified. I tested this locally on Apache 2.2.22 (OS X Lion's native version) and it worked.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)html/$ /$1html [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: If you're putting the .htaccess in the gmap directory, you'll have to use the following in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /eric/tools/gmap/
RewriteRule ^(.+)html/$ $1html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Weird: that resolved to http://meyerweb.com/hydesim.html?dll=40.71427,-74.00597&yd=10&zm=12&op=156 .  (Still does, as I write this.)

Comment: Is your .htaccess in the gmap directory?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Currently the only rule in that file is the one you posted.

Comment: Check the updated answer for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use the QSA ("Query String Append") flag instead of trying to parse it out yourself. Something like:

`RewriteRule ^(.+)html/(.+)$ /$1html [R=301,L,QSA]`

Comment: Hm, doesn’t seem to work.  Here’s my .htaccess:

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.+)html/(.+)$ /$1html [R=301,L,QSA]

The slash still doesn’t get dropped.